# Django populate formset data when editing form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two models `Chapter` and `ChapterQuestion`.

I'm using `formset` to create multiple `ChapterQuestion` records while creating `Chapter` record and it's working fine.

But, when I edit the form, it does not populate formset values.

I'm using `UpdateView` to update the record

```
class EditChapter(UpdateView):
    model = Chapter
    form_class = ChapterForm
    template_name = 'courses/chapter/edit_chapter.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditChapter, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        course = Course.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['course_id'])

        if course is None:
            messages.error(self.request, 'Course not found')
            return reverse('course:list')
        context['course'] = course

        if self.request.POST:
            context['chapter_questions'] = ChapterQuestionFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['chapter_questions'] = ChapterQuestionFormSet()

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        chapter_questions = context['chapter_questions']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

        if chapter_questions.is_valid():
            chapter_questions.instance = self.object
            # chapter_questions.instance.created_by = self.request.user
            chapter_questions.save()

        return super(EditChapter, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('course:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['course_id']})

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(self.__class__, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The `urls.py` contains

```
path('<course_id>/chapter/<uuid:pk>/edit', EditChapter.as_view(), name='edit_chapter'),
```

and in template, I'm using `crispy form`

```
<form method="POST" role="form" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <h3 class="panel-title">Chapter Detail</h3>
    <label for="chapter-name">Chapter Name</label>
    <input name="name"
           placeholder="Chapter Name"
           value="{{ chapter.name }}"
           id="chapter-name">

    <h3 class="panel-title">Add Question to Chapter</h3>

    {{ chapter_questions|crispy }}
</form>
```

`{{ chapter_questions|crispy }}` renders the form fields but fields are empty.

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, inlineformset_factory
from courses.models import Chapter, ChapterQuestion

class ChapterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = ['name']

class ChapterQuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ChapterQuestion
        fields = ['word', 'definition']

ChapterQuestionFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Chapter, ChapterQuestion,
                                               form=ChapterQuestionForm, extra=2)
```

This renders 2 empty set of fields for `ChapterQuestion`.

**How to populated already saved data with formset?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass instance as shown here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

In your case:

```
context['chapter_questions'] = ChapterQuestionFormSet(instance=self.object)
```